# How do I split flat file data and load into parent-child tables in database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import, ssis, etl

I have denormalized data (coming from a file) that needs to be imported into parent-child tables.  The source data is something like this:

```
Account#    Name        Membership    Email
101         J Burns     Gold          alpha@foo.com
101         J Burns     Gold          bravo@foo.com
101         J Burns     Gold          charlie@yay.com
227         H Gordon    Silver        red@color.com
350         B Clyde     Silver        italian@food.com
350         B Clyde     Silver        mexican@food.com
```

What are the pieces, parts, or tactics of SSIS I should use to read the first three columns into a parent table, and the 4th column (Email) into a child table?  I have several options for the parent key which I am permitted to take:

- Directly use the Account# as the primary key
- Use a surrogate key generated by SSIS during the import process
- Configure an identity primary key

I'm sure I've listed my primary key options in increasing order of difficulty.  I'd be interested in knowing how to do the first and the last option - I'll infer how to achieve the middle option.  To emphasize again, *I'm interested in a decidedly SSIS solution; I'm looking for an answer that uses the language of SSIS, rather than a procedural, technology neutral answer.*

My question is somewhat similar to [another SO question](https://cid-4114fe94ba584af5.office.live.com/edit.aspx/.Documents/Work2010?&wd=target%28ClickSquared.one%7CAD681DBC-71A4-4AA8-A58D-90EA5FFCFF3F/Sovereign%20EState%7CA42C7230-D077-4680-831C-AE77404921E4/%29), having an answer of vague viability.  I'm hoping more detailed guidance could be given.  I already know how to solve this problem by creating a "staging" middle-step, where the parent-child separation is actually handled with straight SQL.  However, I'm curious about how this can be done without that kind of middle-step.

It seems to me this kind of import would be so common, that there would be a well-published formulaic way to handle it - a technique that SSIS excels at.  As yet, I've not quite seen any straight up answer to this.

**`Update #1`**: Based on comments, I've adjusted the sample data to be more obviously denormalized.  I also removed "flat" from "flat file," so that semantics don't interfere with the question.

**`Update #2`**: I've amplified my interest in a solution spoken in the language of SSIS.

Comment: I see no parent-child relationship in the data you've supplied.  It looks like the second table in a one-to-many scenario.

Comment: +1 @Steve - this isn't denormalized OR flat.

Comment: I have adjusted the question per your comments.  Have a suggested answer?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is one possible option that you can consider in loading parent-child data. This option consists of two steps. In the **first** step, read the source file and write data to parent table. In the **second** step, read the source file again and use lookup transformation to fetch the parent info in order to write data to the child table. Following example uses the data provided in the question. This example was created using SSIS 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 database.

**Step-by-Step process:**

1. Create a sample flat file named `Source.txt` as shown in screenshot #**1**.
2. In the SQL database, create two tables named `dbo.Parent` and `dbo.Child` using the scripts given under **SQL Scripts** section. Both the tables have an auto generated identity column.
3. On the package, place an `OLE DB connection` to connect to the SQL Server and `Flat File connection` to read the source file as shown in screenshot #**2**. Configure the flat file connection as shown in screenshots #**3** - #**9**.
4. On the Control Flow tab, place two `Data Flow Tasks` as shown in screenshot #**10**.
5. Inside the data flow task named **Parent**, place a Flat File source, Sort transformation and an OLE DB destination as shown in screenshot #**11**.
6. Configure the flat file source as shown in screenshots #**12** and #**13**. We need to read the flat file source.
7. Configure the sort transformation as shown in screenshot #**14**. We need to eliminate the duplicate values so that only the unique records are inserted into the parent table `dbo.Parent`.
8. Configure the ole db destination as shown in screenshots #**15** and #**16**. We need to insert the data into the parent table `dbo.Parent`.
9. Inside the data flow task named **Child**, place a Flat File source, Lookup transformation and an OLE DB destination as shown in screenshot #**17**.
10. Configure the flat file source as shown in screenshots #**12** and #**13**. This configuration is same as the flat file source in the previous data flow task.
11. Configure the lookup transformation as shown in screenshots #**18** and #**20**. We need to find the parent id from the table `dbo.Parent` using the other key columns present in the file. The key columns here are the Account, Name and Email. If the file happened to have a unique column, you could just use that column alone to fetch the parent id.
12. Configure the ole db destination as shown in screenshots #**21** and #**22**. We need to insert the Email column along with the Parent id into the table `dbo.Child`.
13. Screenshot #**23** shows data in the tables **before** the package execution.
14. Screenshots #**24** and #**25** show sample package execution.
15. Screenshot #**26** shows data in the tables **after** the package execution.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Child](
    [ChildId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](21) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Child] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ChildId] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parent](
    [ParentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Account] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [Membership] [varchar](14) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ParentId] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

**Screenshot #12:**

[image: 12]

**Screenshot #13:**

[image: 13]

**Screenshot #14:**

[image: 14]

**Screenshot #15:**

[image: 15]

**Screenshot #16:**

[image: 16]

**Screenshot #17:**

[image: 17]

**Screenshot #18:**

[image: 18]

**Screenshot #19:**

[image: 19]

**Screenshot #20:**

[image: 20]

**Screenshot #21:**

[image: 21]

**Screenshot #22:**

[image: 22]

**Screenshot #23:**

[image: 23]

**Screenshot #24:**

[image: 24]

**Screenshot #25:**

[image: 25]

**Screenshot #26:**

[image: 26]

Comment: Holy Mother of God.  I have never seen an answer so detailed, and so carefully presented.  You are incredible!

Comment: Perhaps you you should mark his post as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sorted and Account# is an integer I would:

Insert the emails into a table (add an auto increment column, it's a best practise).

```
1  101    alpha@foo.com
2  101    bravo@foo.com
3  101    charlie@yay.com
etc.
```

Then I would insert the other records to a parent table.

- using Account# as the primary key
- omitting the email addresses
- skipping duplicates (easy if the data
  is sorted).

If you have a foreign key relationship setup, you will need to do the second step first (to avoid having any orphan records).

My two cents:  I don't know what your requirements are but it seems a bit over-normalized.  If there is a small limit on the number of email addresses, I would consider adding several email columns to the main table...for speed and simplicity.

Comment: Due to my infamiliarity with SSIS, I've adjusted my question to place extra-emphasis on a solution spoken in the language of SSIS.  That is, something that sounds like "Create a flat file source container, and hook it to a foreach loop container, then add a data flow task to the foreach loop container. etc. etc."