# Using a variety of integer types for primary key

Tags: database-migration, ssis

I'm pretty new to SSIS and I'm trying to convert old database data into a new database schema. I've been playing around a while, but I cannot get my head around how I would be able to keep the integrity between 2 or more destination sources. For example, I have a projects table in the old database (projects for buildings), which contains the following information:

```
+------------------------+
+ TABLE: Projects        +
+------------------------+
+ ProjectID (PK)         + (primary key of project)
+ ProjectCode            + (unique code of the project)
+ ProjectBuildingName    + (name of the building for this project)
+ ProjectCompletionDate  + (date when the project has been completed)
+ AddressLine1           + (AddressLine, Postalcode and City of the building)
+ Postalcode             +
+ City                   +
+------------------------+
```

In my new database design, I want to split the data of [Projects] into the tables: [Projects], [Projectbuildings] and [Addresses].

In SSIS, I select the old.[Projects] table as source, and map these to the corresponding sources. Before that, I convert the data, and do a multicast, see figure below:

[image]

In this flow I migrate the data I want to the tables I want, but those tables won't have their FK-integrity. For example, my new design would look like this:

```
+--------------------------+
+ TABLE: Projects          +
+--------------------------+
+ ProjectID (PK)           +
+ ProjectCode              +
+ ProjectCompletionDate    +
+ ProjectBuildingID (FK)   +
+--------------------------+

+--------------------------+
+ TABLE: ProjectBuildings  +
+--------------------------+
+ ProjectBuildingID (PK)   +
+ ProjectBuildingName      +
+ AddressID (FK)           +
+--------------------------+

+--------------------------+
+ TABLE: Addresses         +
+--------------------------+
+ AddressID (PK)           +
+ Country                  +
+ City                     +
+ Postalcode               +
+ AddressLine1             +
+--------------------------+
```

*(P.S. Ignore the 4th column in the figure, which would be the [Contacts] column. This is a limited data example to help me point out my question)*

When I now map 1 on 1, I do transfer the data in the correct tables and columns, but how am I going to ensure that all tables have their relations linked to each other in the correct way as well?

I have seen 2 other stackoverflow posts about more or less the same question, but I just can't get around it. I was hoping for a more clear answer.

*Note: I'm using SQL Server 2008 Data Center + Integrated Services with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. I'm trying to migrate from old to new database, both on the same SQL Server 2008.*

**EDIT**
I have found a very great explanation at [How do I split flat file data and load into parent-child tables in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658484/how-do-i-split-flat-file-data-and-load-into-parent-child-tables-in-database).

I managed to split a table into two tables (a child and a parent), insert into the parent, then lookup the inserted ID, and use that ID for the insertion of the child. Problems occur when this child is also a parent of the 3rd table. I would think that running the same flow for the 2nd child would be the same: lookup ID of the inserted ID of child1, then use that when inserting child2. For some reason, it's not really working.

**EDIT**
Ok, here is the real example. I'm trying to migrate the following columns out of the old database (which is all in 1 table):

```
[OLDDB].Customersurname        ---->     [People].Surname
[OLDDB].Customerforename       ---->     [People].Forename
[OLDDB].Customergender         ---->     [People].bGender
[OLDDB].Customeraddressline    ---->     [Addresses].AddressLine1
[OLDDB].Customerpostalcode     ---->     [Addresses].Postalcode
[OLDDB].Customercity           ---->     [Addresses].City
[OLDDB].Customerphone          ---->     [AdditionalAddresses].Phone1
[OLDDB].Customeremail          ---->     [AdditionalAddresses].Email
```

[image]

Now I managed to insert [AdditionalAddresses] and [Addresses] with their corresponding links (and left Countries and AddressTypes NULL). My problem is the [Contacts] table, which only contains the [Address].AddressID and the boolean which tells if the [Contact] is a person or a company. I think, if [People] and [Companies] both would contain the [Address].AddressID as FK, it would work.

So what I have done so far is:

1. Migrate to [AdditionalAddresses] (DONE)
2. Lookup parent [AdditionalAddresses] key (DONE)
3. Export to [Addresses] based on lookup key of [AdditionalAddresses] (DONE)

Next I would:

5. Export to [People], this will create new unique ID's and I will have to put the FK constraint off
6. Lookup parent [People] keys
7. Export to [Contacts] based on lookup key of [People]

Then the last part, to update the [Contacts] table with the [Address].AddressID that belongs to that person...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few questions to precise your need:

- Is it a oneshot operation or not ?
- Are the target tables empty ?
- Do you do a lot of data tranformation/conversion ?

Two options to investigate in the meantime:

- One of the easiest solution would be to split your *dataflow* in four distinct *dataflows*, ordered by precedence constraints. In the first one you extract and load the *Projects*. In the second one you extract the *ProjectBuildings*, do a lookup into your *Projects* table to get the corresponding ProjectID and then insert it.
- Another option would be to use staging tables, but it seems way overkill for the case you are presenting.

Comment: I have around 15.000 records out of 30 database tables which I will need to migrate over 80 tables, which will give a lot more records, guessing at least the double - so I will have to do a lot of transformation.

I indeed figured out the lookup ID at that link, it also described a nice way to do it. Now trying to do the same at the child node of the first child, which for some reason is not working out.

Comment: Could you post an example of what is not working in your edit ? Do you ensure the operations happen in the correct order ? 1. Insert parent 2. Insert child1 (with lookup to parent) 3. Insert child2 (with lookup to child1). This should work.

Comment: The question then is whether or not the content of your *Contacts* table (the three fields + address) allows you to find a unique *Contact* for any record in your OLDDB.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't

Comment: All hope is not lost. Another option (much less elegant) would be to add an extra column in your *Contacts* table, containing an identifier, for example the ID from your OLDDB table. You can then insert the *Contacts* with the extra ID. When you load the *Persons* you know the OLDDB.ID and you can easily lookup the corresponding contact.

Comment: This solution is not perfect because it messes up your datamodel with a extra field (that you can later drop if it is a one shot operation). The last solution I know of without the same caveats but much more complex (use of a stored procedure and more complex flows) is described here : http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.be/2011/08/inserting-records-and-getting-identity.html

Comment: I managed to extract information out of 1 old database table into 10 new ones keeping referential integrity, by using the temporarily added ID columns. Thanks a lot! This I find a real quick and easy solution (performance is not an issue for this relatively small database). It don't require me to find candidate keys as look-up from the previous insert operation, for which I also would have to make sure that they are unique as combination. At the end of the flow, I can just drop this column as well, so eventually this is a suitable solution/workaround for every operation.